# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) odoo14

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, odoo, odoo-14

I use Odoo 14 enterprise hosted on premise
I duplicated my database then I had this error :  502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
I restart the nginx and Odoo service, nothing change.
how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

First enter to the database user,then stop the server and next go for restart

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).